# What does declare var HTMLDivElement { new(), prototype } mean

Tags: typescript, new-operator

lib.d.ts holds the declaration:

```
interface HTMLDivElement extends HTMLElement, ... {}

declare var HTMLDivElement: {
    prototype: HTMLDivElement;   // additional q: what does this mean?
    new(): HTMLDivElement;       // q: what does this mean?
}
```

I guess the prototype allows to add more methods to the div (while enhancing builtin js types is not overly recommended anyway) but have less guess about what the new() means.

What does this declaration mean, why is it necessary or helpful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an overview of those lines...

```
new(): HTMLDivElement;
```

This means that when you create an instance, the type of that instance will be `HTMLDivElement`. For example...

```
var elem = new HTMLDivElement(); // elem is of type HTMLDivElement
```

What this really does is tell the compiler you can create instances of this object (this is needed because it isn't declared as a class). Without this line in the declaration you would get an "invalid new expression" error when you compiler the code that creates an instance.

**NOTE**: You will get a runtime error in this specific case, because as far as I can tell a `HTMLDivElement` shouldn't be "newable". If `new(): HTMLDivELement;` was removed from lib.d.ts the compiler would actually correctly warn you that you can't do this.

```
prototype: HTMLDivElement;
```

Without this line of code you will be able to use methods and properties on an instance of the object, but you won't be able to override the prototype:

```
HTMLDivElement.prototype.getAttribute = function (name?: string) {
    return 'Go Away';
}
```

Comment: Hm, but if you seriously execute the line "var elem = new HTMLDivElement();" it will fail in Chrome, FF and IE11 and it is not the DOM spec either. So why then is it defined? Your prototype explanation is what I expected, considered solved.

Comment: Yes - as a real life example, I don't know why you would make `HTMLDivElement` newable. I can't see anything in `lib.d.ts` that would rely on that. If you were to remove that line, I don't think any code would break (based on some quick tests in the TypeScript playground). Even in cases where it is appropriate, you wouldn't use the `HTML...Element` - for example to create a new HTMLImageElement, you would use Image... `var img: HTMLImageElement = new Image();`

Comment: Agreed. Presumably we should not overstress perfectness of lib.d.ts at the pre 1.0 stage of typescript.